# How destroy (de-istantiate) or change reference for a xml view?

Tags: sapui5

By this code I instantiate a xml-view and associate it to a name:

```
sap.ui.xmlview(welcomeApp, "apps.app1.welcomePage")
```

I want change set apps.app2.welcomePage to my new welcomePage xml view...

How can I destroy (de-istantiate) the view (after I re-istantiate it by the new path) or change the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Routing](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/acdb6cd408ec4b9eb5e1fe45e607abdd.html) to handle navigation from view to view. Please check out this step by step [example](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/688f36bd758e4ce2b4e682eef4dc794e.html) to understanding UI5 routing mechanism.